# MRTG: ERROR: did not find any matching data in cfg file

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have VPS server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm installing MRTG. I used install snmpd apach2 mrtg. I made cfg file vytv cfgmaker and edited it:

```
RunAsDaemon: Yes
Interval: 5
Logdir: /var/log/
EnableIPv6: no
```

And as last I want to make index file with indexmaker index.html but I get error:
*ERROR: did not find any matching data in cfg file*

My command: 
*indexmaker --output=/var/www/mrtg/index.html /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg*

I found http://piserv.nl/blog/index.php/mrtg-on-the-raspberry-pi/ . There is tutorial to edit snmpd but it makes no change.

Answer (score 3):

Paste your mrtg.cfg file here. Usually this happens when mrtg can't find any line to create an index for it. Means lines are commented out or they start with blank space. Make sure the blocks regarding your network interface definition are not commented out and don't have any space at beginning of the line.

```
Target[127.0.0.1_1]: 1:public@127.0.0.1:
SetEnv[127.0.0.1_1]: MRTG_INT_IP="127.0.0.1" MRTG_INT_DESCR="lo"
MaxBytes[127.0.0.1_1]: 1250000
Title[127.0.0.1_1]: Traffic Analysis for local loopback
PageTop[127.0.0.1_1]: <h1>Traffic Analysis for local loopback</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you get this **ERROR: did not find any matching** data in cfg file just go to **/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf** and uncomment this line **rocommunity public localhost**, after this you need to restart the snmp, **/etc/init.d/snmpd restart**﻿

// i'm using ubuntu 14.04